# Data not present in redux store despite already loaded

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux

I have two components:

```
class A extends Component { }

class B extends Component { }
```

class A loads some data into the `store` and clicking on a button in class A will change the route to class B

In class B, I'm trying to access the store using `mapStateToProps`, but the data put into the store by class A has become empty.

`console.log()` in class A's mapStateToProps is showing the data but the same in class B is showing an empty JSON.

class B doesn't dispatch any action on the store. It just needs the data already in the store.

Both the components are under the same `Provider`.

Not sure what might be the problem.

Class A:

```js
class A extends Component {
 componentWillMount() {
  const { id, loadAction } = this.props;
  loadAction(id);
 }

 render() {
  ....
  <Button label="Label" href="/b"/>
 }
}


const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
console.log("State: " + JSON.stringify(state));
return {
 id: state.id,
 details: state.details,//populated after loadAction
}};

const mapDispatchToProps = {
 loadAction: loadAction,
};

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(A);
```

Class B:

```js
class B extends Component {
 
 render() {
  const { details } = this.props;

  //details is null here
 }
}

const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
console.log("State: " + JSON.stringify(state));
return {
 details: state.details,
}
};

export default connect(mapStateToProps)(B);
```

Comment: Maybe it's a timing issue of sorts, have you tried looking at the state using the redux dev tool?

Comment: More information required. Perhaps you can show us the code?

Comment: @NicolasGaller Not sure how it can be a timing issue because a log in component A's mapStateToProps shows the already loaded data. component B is loaded after that. Another thing I noticed is that values of all the keys in store are shown as null in component B but all are populated in component A

Comment: can you please post the relevant, really hard to debug with this.

Comment: Added some more code..